# Using Bintray generic repo with PIP

Tags: pip, pypi, bintray, jfrog-cli

I am trying to find out if I can use bintray as python packages repo. I see that bintray does not provide PyPi repo type -  https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/BT/Supported+Package+Formats.

I am wondering how do I use generic bintray repo to get it working with PIP. When I tried creating a package and version in generic repo, to access it we need to know exact file name. I tried setting PIP_INDEX_URL something like this and it does not work.

```
https://user:API_KEY@bintray.com/myUser/my-pypi-repo/
```

I do know that I can download the files to local and install using pip, but that will make managing versions very complex.

Only thing I can do it use 'curl' or 'wget' with exact file path to download. Any suggestions will be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use PiPy [Basic Authentication](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#basic-authentication-credentials).
The install command you need to use is:

```
pip install my-pypi-package --index-url=https://dl.bintray.com/myUser/my-pypi-repo/
```

For private repository, you'll need to add credentials:

```
pip install my-pypi-package --index-url=https://username:api_key@dl.bintray.com/myUser/my-pypi-repo/
```

Remember to have all the required files under this path `https://dl.bintray.com/myUser/my-pypi-repo/`

Comment: So I have created a package called six and have a version called latest and put all my files in '/' path. 

pip -v install six --index-url=https://user:api_key@dl.bintray.com/my-pypi/  I do this and it throws 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://dl.bintray.com/my-pypi/six/

Comment: I think you are missing the **https**, should be `https://user:api_key@dl.bintray.com/user-name/repoitory-name/...`

Comment: Can you please add the link to your repository?